# Ext sheaves of Ideal Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety (over $\Bbb{C}$) and $Y\subset X$ a smooth codimension one irreducible subvariety.

How to compute the Ext sheaves $\mathrm{Ext}^i(I_Y,O_X)$ ?

In particular, when $\dim X=2$ and $Y=C$ is a curve, is it true that
$$\mathrm{Ext}^2(I_C,O_X)=N_{C/X}$$
where $N_{C/X}$ is the (direct image of) the normal bundle of $C$ in $X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of your interest, one usually writes $\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)$ for $I_Y$, and it is a line bundle. One has the natural exact sequence, $0\to \mathcal{O}_X(-Y)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_Y\to 0$, which by dualizing gives, $0\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X(Y)\to Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{O}_X)\to 0$ (here ext denotes sheaf ext, but similar calculations can be made for global ext too). Thus, one gets $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{O}_X)=N_{Y/X}$, higher exts zero. Also, since $I_Y$ is a line bundle, $Ext^i(I_Y,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for all $i>0$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when you dualize the natural exact sequence you get another short exact sequence with $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{O}_X)$ as the third factor; otherwise, if you tensor the natural exact sequence by $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$ you get a similar short exact sequence but now you have $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)=N_{Y/X}$ as the third factor and then you can conclude that the two sheaves are isomorphic?